# MahApps.Metro AnimatedSingleRowTabControl doesn't work

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

For some reason my Tab Control doesn't seem to work as described.

Instead of seeing this (From Mahapps site)
[image]

I see this
[image]

I have tried fiddling with every single property to try to get the scroll bar to go away and to have left/right scroll buttons as shown in the example, but absolutely nothing works.

What am I missing?

**EDIT: - Added my XAML**

```
        <Controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl Controls:TabControlHelper.IsUnderlined="True" Margin="5" ScrollViewer.PanningMode="Both" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <Controls:MetroTabItem Header="Thread Image Download">

            </Controls:MetroTabItem>
            <Controls:MetroTabItem Header="Random Board Stats">

            </Controls:MetroTabItem>
        </Controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't exist a style key for this `TabControl`. So you must add the resource dictionary to the place where you need it. So MahApps should solve this in the next releases (site note for me).

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.AnimatedSingleRowTabControl.xaml" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="this tabcontrols tabs">
            <TextBlock FontSize="30" Text="Content" />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="appear only on a single line">
            <TextBlock FontSize="30" Text="Content" />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="if they are overflowing">
            <TextBlock FontSize="30" Text="Content" />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="instead of wrapping them">
            <TextBlock FontSize="30" Text="Content" />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked perfectly! I'm just so used to using the keys that I never thought to try this.

Comment: @punker Is this issue fixed? How can I use `MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl` with visual studio style tabs?

Comment: @punker76 If i'm not mistaken it looks like the issues still isn't fixed. Using this method, how would you go about customizing the arrows?